# "Born"— Adjective or Verb in this context?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, parts-of-speech

Her brother was born blind.

In this context,"Born" is an *Adjective* or *verb*?

Webster defines it as "Adjective" while OALD defines it as "Verb".

Comment: idiom: to be born

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Her brother [was born blind].*

"Born" is a verb here.

The past participle of the verb "bear" is spelled "born" only in the passive, in the childbirth sense, thus *was born blind* is passive; a short passive, of course, since there is no possibility of a *by* phrase being added: we can't say **He was born blind by a Greek peasant.*